# Pass List<T> to SQLite query via AddRange

Tags: c#, sqlite, parameters

Consider the table:

```
CREATE TABLE claim(
   id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
   date DATETIME,
   applicant TEXT
);
```

C#:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "1234", "034234", "34213" };
```

How to properly utilize cmd.Parameters.AddRange function to SELECT * FROM claim WHERE id IN (myList)?
I want to escape having to glue strings and do it parametrized way.

Comment: var x = _dataContext.claim
                               .Where(t => idList.Contains(t.id));

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
string.Format($" select * from claim where id in ({String.Join(", ", myList.ToArray())})")
```

of course if you want to use this for more tables, just create a method from the whole thing:

```
public string GetCMD(string tableName, List<string> whereIn)
{
    return string.Format($" select * from {tableName} where id in ({String.Join(", ", whereIn.ToArray())})");
}
```

Comment: but this is exactly what I've been trying to avoid. This approach does not use parametrization

Comment: in these times write your own easy queries like that is nonsense anymore. Use some code first (or DB first) and you will have everything in objects directly, then you can use what vivek wrote in his comment.

Comment: also AddRange accepts Array, so why don't you use just
myList.ToArray()?